# create zip from xml in utf-8 encoding

Tags: c#, xml, zip

I have string with xml which i need to make zip (in utf-8) and convert zip to byte array (why i belive it all should be done in memorystream). Right now I have something like this but I'm not exactly know what do next.

```cs
class Test
{
   private string Xml = "<test:doc id=\"1\">" + 
                        "<test:doc1 name=\"abcd\"/>" +
                        ... etc
                        "</test:doc>";
    
   private byte[] XmlTest(string Xml)
   {
            XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
            xmlDoc.LoadXml(Xml);
            var buffer = new MemoryStream();
            byte[] bytes;
            
            using (buffer)
            using (var archive = new ZipArchive(buffer, 
                          ZipArchiveMode.Create,true))
            {
                ZipArchiveEntry manifest = 
                   archive.CreateEntry("doc.xml");
                using (Stream st = manifest.Open())
                {
                    using (StreamWriter writerManifest = new StreamWriter(st))
                    {
                        writerManifest.WriteLine(xmlDoc.OuterXml);
                    }
                }

                bytes = buffer.ToArray();
                return bytes;
            }           
        }

}
```

Comment: Why not xmlDoc.ToString()   or use a MemoryStream.

Comment: I'm not shure how?